# Database for sequential data

Tags: mysql, database, qt, embedded, real-time

I'm completely new to databases so pardon the simplicity of the question.  We have an embedded Linux system that needs to store data collected over a time span of several hours.  The data will need to be searchable sequentially and includes data like GPS, environmental data, etc.  This data will need to saved off in a folder on a removable SSD and labeled as a "Mission".  Several "Missions" can exists on a single SSD and should not be mixed together because they need to be copied and saved off individually at the users discretion to external media.  Data will be saved off as often as 10 times a second and needs to be very robust because of the potential for power outages.

The data will need to be searchable on the system it is created on but also after the removalable disk is taken to another system (also Linux) it needs to be loaded and used there also.  In the past we have done custom files to store the data but it seems like a database might be the best option.  How portable are databases like MySQL?  Can a user easily remove a disk with a database on it and plug it in a new machine to use without too much effort?  Our queries will mostly be time based because the user will be "playing" through the data after it is collected in perhaps 10x the collection rate. Also, our base code is written in Qt (C++) so we would need to interact with the database in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with SQLite.  It's small and lite. It stores all its data into one file. You can copy or move the file to another computer and read it there. You data writer can just remake the file, empty when it detects that today's ssd does not already have the file.

It's also worth mentioning that SQLite undergoes [testing](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) at the level afforded only by select few safety-critical pieces of software. The test suite, while partly autogenerated, is a staggering 100 million lines of code. It is not lite at all when it comes to robustness. I would trust SQLite more than a random self-made database implementation.

SQLite is used in certified avionics AFAIK.

Comment: I should mention that "embedded" in this case doesn't mean small or limited in processing power.  The software is running on an expensive 64-bit workstation motherboard with dual-hex cores and tons of RAM.  It's just happens to be in a helicopter.

Comment: Still, the whole database can live in one file, which you can physically carry to a new machine and read.